# How to Delete from multiple joined tables in CodeIgniter.

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have Four Tables.

```
Tbl_plan (plan_id,plan_name)
Tbl_Task (task_id,plan_name_id,task_name)
Tbl_move (move_id,task_name_id)
Tbl_Pass (pass_id,move_idd,pass_name)
```

And All four tables are Joined through these fields.

```
tbl_plan.plan_id=tbl_task.plan_name_id
tbl_task.task_id=tbl_move.task_name_id
tbl_move.move_id=tbl_pass.move_idd
```

I want one delete button, through i delete data from all tables against one id or any other way.

Comment: You can use foreign key constraint in your table structure. Here for details https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: on delete cascade on update cascade

Comment: I used all tables primary key into other table as a foreign key.
Key you write query for delete?